# Eclipse debugger: ".settings does not exist" error

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a C++ application in Eclipse under Ubuntu Linux 10.10. When I launch the application that I develop in debug mode then Eclipse correctly switches to the debug perspective, but it tries to open a file (?) called ".settings", which does not exist in my project directory (but there is indeed a directory with that name there). I can see that Eclipse supends the running thread at the right source code location (based on the stack trace), but that source file is not opened, nor does the "debug step" move the current instruction pointer to the next statement.

It basically seems to be the same error as here: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg08774.html -- unfortunately the solution there is to update Eclipse to 3.1.5, but I am using version 3.5.2 already, so that does not do the trick for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance, Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Try to open all projects that are on the source file's path. I've experienced something similar with Java and a hierarchical project and that did solve my problem.